# How to make mtlLoader, and objloader wait for material texture to be loaded, before continuing with the rest of the program?

Tags: three.js

Please take a look at [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/avnerm/n1bkrx68/50/)

The scene is static so it should be enough to explicitly call `renderer.render()` command once, after the assets are loaded, and see the head.
But the head is not seen.

If I replace `renderer.render( scene, camera );` with `animate()` (set `doRenderViaSingleRender = false`) the head is seen.

I think that the failure when calling `render()` once, is because the texture is not yet loaded.
Whereas, `animate()` calls `render()` constantly, and so, when the texture is finally loaded, the head is seen.

After setting the materials in `objLoader.setMaterials( materials );` I expect the map to be defined, but it is undefined.
the console log of the material map shows:

```
console.log('objLoader.materials.materials[lambert2SG.001].map', objLoader.materials.materials['lambert2SG.001'].map);
null
```

How can I make the program wait until after the texture has been loaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That material doesn't have a map set. If you open the material file https://threejs.org/examples/models/obj/walt/WaltHead.mtl in a text editor you'll see it has several attributes, but you won't find a path to a texture, so that's why performing `console.log()` on the map property outputs `null`.

```
# Material Count: 1
newmtl lambert2SG.001
Ns 92.156863
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.250000 0.250000 0.250000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
```

Additionally, that WaltHead object file has vertex position and normals but it does not have any UV data, so even if you assigned a map texture, it won't display without UVs.

However, to answer your question, you could manually download any texture with `TextureLoader.load()`. The first argument is the path to the texture file, and [the second argument is the callback](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/TextureLoader.load) function that's triggered after the texture has finished loading.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I created another test that uses a material with texture, and updated my question above.

Comment: @AvnerMoshkovitz I believe I answered your original question, please limit the scope of each post to one question each, instead of adding more to the first one after it's been answered. This is a different question altogether, you should make a new post with the new question.

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer.
I posted a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65526329/how-to-use-async-await-when-loading-a-material-texture-image) regarding how to  
use async/await/loadAsync() to insure that the texture is loaded before continuing the program.