# How to use async/await when loading a material texture image

Tags: three.js

I have a .obj, and .mtl with texture image that I want to render.
The scene is static so I want to render by explicitly calling the `renderer.render()` command once (and not use animate()), after the assets are loaded, and see the texture.
But the texture is not seen.

To wait until the texture is loaded, I:

- call loadAsync() instead of load(), when loading the .mtl and the .obj files
- add await before some of the calls (mtlLoader.loadAsync, materials.preload, objLoader.loadAsync)
- change the file MTLLoader, OBJLoader slightly, compared to the reference (from threejs/releases/three.js-r120/examples/jsm/loaders/MTLLoader.js)
  (the changes are to accommodate the async/await changes)

The changes work, but don't fully understand why, and would like to know.
Specifically, I have a question regarding placing async/await in one of the functions (MTLLoader.MaterialCreator::create)

In example13_MTLLoader.js, this is the program flow:

```
MTLLoader.MaterialCreator::preload
  MTLLoader.MaterialCreator::create
    MTLLoader.MaterialCreator::createMaterial_
```

in example13_OBJLoader.js, this is the program flow:

```
OBJLoader::parse
  MTLLoader.MaterialCreator::create
```

I placed `async/await` in the `MTLLoader.MaterialCreator` functions: `preload, create, createMaterial_`.
The rational was to wait for the texture to be loaded before continuing the program.

---

**UseCase1**
In this case:

- The texture is loaded before the program continues. This can be seen in the log where:

  - the material is defined
    `objLoader.materials.materials {test2: MeshPhongMaterial}`
  - the map image is defined
    `objLoader.materials.materials.test2.map.image <img crossorigin=​"anonymous" src=​"http:​/​/​127.0.0.1:​8080/​./​test2.jpg">​`
- But the texture is not displayed
  The code for this case can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/avnerm/Lduk89nq/14/)

---

**UseCase2**
If I take-out the `async/await` from `MTLLoader.MaterialCreator::create`

- The texture is NOT loaded before the program continues. This can be seen in the log where:

  - the materials list is empty
    `objLoader.materials.materials {}`
  - the material test2 is undefined
    `objLoader.materials.materials.test2 undefined`
- But the texture is displayed...
  The code for this case can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/avnerm/Lduk89nq/19/)
  (for some reason I need to click *Run* in *jsfiddle* multiple times, to see the texture, otherwise only a white patch is seen)

---

The only change between the 2 cases is in the value of `MTLLoader.MaterialCreator::doUseCreateWithAsync = false/true`
(the behaviour for the 2 cases is the same for single render or `animate()`)

**Why when placing `async/await` in `MTLLoader.MaterialCreator::create,` the texture is not seen?**

Thanks